# Why is sed not matching excess whitespace between non-whitespace characters

Tags: sed

I have a sed oneliner which removes excess whitespace:

```
sed -e 's/^\s*//' -e 's/\s*$//' -e 's/\s{2,}/ /g'
```

When I test it on `"  \tone1   two\t3three\t "`, the sed removes the whitespace at the beginning and end of the line but doesn't match the excess whitespace between words, and sed returns `\tone1   two\t3three`. What I want is `\tone1 two 3three`, so `sed -e 's/[ \t]{2,}/ /g'` is not functioning.

regexr.com shows the expression as functional.

My version is GNU sed version 4.2.1.

Comment: I think the braces need to be escaped. But you don't need them anyway. Just do `'s/\s\+/ /g'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{` and `}` need to be escaped in basic regex mode that `sed` uses.

However, you can use this `sed` with a single substitution with **alternation**:

```
sed -E 's/^[[:blank:]]+|[[:blank:]]+$|[[:blank:]]{2,}//g' file
```

POSIX character class `[[:blank:]]` matches a space or tab characters.

Comment: I'm guessing `[[:blank:]]+{2,}` is a typo, and you either meant `[[:blank:]]+` or `[[:blank:]]{2,}`.

Comment: Indeed, it was a typo. Thanks!

Comment: So I've rewritten it to `sed -r 's/[[:blank:]]+/ /g;s/^\s|\s$//g'`, but why does `[[:blank:]]` work and not `\s`?

Comment: No, it is now working. The one caveat is that the single substitution does not remove the leading or trailing whitespace. My final answer was `sed -r 's/\s+/ /g;s/^\s|\s$//g'`